# Combining two CASE statements with the same condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to improve the efficiency of the following query?

```
SELECT shiftid,
 
CASE flag  
    WHEN 'Y' THEN driver_code
    Else spare_code
END AS Dcode,
CASE flag  
    WHEN 'Y' THEN driver_name
    Else spare_name
END AS Dname,
FROM shiftmaster;
```

Although it is working fine but as the condition is same, I want to check it only once.

Comment: show your dataset and desired outcome.

Comment: In general, You have to write separate case expression for for individual columns. One case expression can produce dqta for only one expression(column in final result)

Comment: *I want to check it only once* Why? This won't improve, shown query looks like optimal.

Comment: Two case _expressions_.

Comment: Your code is fine.  There is really no way to optimize this query.

Answer (score 1):

It's the optimized option. But you need to remove ',' after **DName** or you will have syntax error. But if your goal is to set the condition once for each column you can do it with left outer join (should be slower than your query) as below:

**Alternate query with single condition for all columns:**

```
SELECT sm.shiftid
    , COALESCE(smd.driver_code, sm.spare_code) as Dcode
    , COALESCE(smd.driver_name, sm.spare_name) as DName
FROM shiftmaster  AS sm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (   SELECT shiftid, driver_code, driver_name
                        FROM shiftmaster 
                        WHERE flag = 'Y'
                        ) AS smd ON smd.shiftid = sm.shiftid
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Original query after removing unnecessary comma(,):**

```
SELECT shiftid, 
CASE flag  
    WHEN 'Y' THEN driver_code
    Else spare_code
END AS Dcode,
CASE flag  
    WHEN 'Y' THEN driver_name
    Else spare_name
END AS Dname
FROM shiftmaster;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, here's another way of saying the same thing (minus the syntax error), but it doesn't save you anything...

```
SELECT shiftid
     , driver_code dcode
     , driver_name dname
  FROM shiftmaster
 WHERE flag = 'Y'
UNION ALL    
SELECT shiftid
     , spare_code  
     , spare_name
  FROM shiftmaster
 WHERE flag <> 'Y'
```

Comment: Will save some rows if the flag column has null values.

Comment: I'm baffled by how such an answer can be upvoted.  The OP is asking about *performance* and this would scan the table twice --- presumably doubling the time.